# My code is taking too long at time of execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

This is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double prate = 0;
        double srate = 0;
        double rate = 0;
        double qty = 0;
        double val = 0; bool b = false;
        List<string> item = new List<string>();
        List<string> brand = new List<string>();
        List<string> station = new List<string>();
        List<string> dealer = new List<string>();
        int m1=0, m2=0;
        for (int k = 0; k < treeView1.Nodes.Count; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < treeView1.Nodes[k].Nodes.Count; l++)
            {

                if (treeView1.Nodes[k].Nodes[l].Checked == true)
                {
                    brand.Add(treeView1.Nodes[k].Tag.ToString());
                    item.Add(treeView1.Nodes[k].Nodes[l].Tag.ToString());
                    m1++;
                }
            }
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < treeView2.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < treeView2.Nodes[i].Nodes.Count; j++)
            {
                if (treeView2.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Checked == true)
                {
                    station.Add(treeView2.Nodes[i].Tag.ToString());
                    dealer.Add(treeView2.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Tag.ToString());
                    m2++;
                }
            }
        }

        string[] brands; string[] items; string[] stations; string[] dealers;
        brands = brand.ToArray();
        items = item.ToArray();
        stations = station.ToArray();
        dealers = dealer.ToArray();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.constr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand del = new SqlCommand("delete PLReport", con);
        del.ExecuteNonQuery();
        del.Dispose();
        for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++)
        {

            prate = 0;
            SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand("select top 1 purchasePrice from PurchaseDetails where ItemCode='" + item[i] + "' order by doc_date Desc", con);
            SqlDataReader drr = cmdr.ExecuteReader();
            while (drr.Read())
            {
                prate = Convert.ToDouble(drr[0]);

            }
            drr.Close();
            cmdr.Dispose();
            for (int j = 0; j < m2; j++)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd33 = new SqlCommand("select slno from SalesDetails where ItemCode='" + items[i] + "' and dealer='" + dealers[j] + "' and date between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader r33 = cmd33.ExecuteReader();
                if (!r33.HasRows)
                    continue;
                r33.Close();
                cmd33.Dispose();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(Qty),sum(rate) from SalesDetails where ItemCode='" + items[i] + "' and dealer='" + dealers[j] + "' and date between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' group by ItemCode,Dealer", con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("fgfg");
                    srate = 0;
                    b = double.TryParse(dr[1].ToString(), out srate);
                    rate = 0;
                    if (srate != 0)
                        rate = srate - prate;
                    qty = 0;
                    b = double.TryParse(dr[0].ToString(), out qty);
                    val = qty * rate;
                    if (checkBox3.Checked)//zero valued entry
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert PLReport values('" + stations[j] + "','" + dealers[j] + "','" + brands[i] + "','" + items[i] + "','" + val + "')", con);
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd2.Dispose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (val != 0)
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert PLReport values('" + stations[j] + "','" + dealers[j] + "','" + brands[i] + "','" + items[i] + "','" + val + "')", con);
                            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            cmd2.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }


        }


            frmPLReport obj = new frmPLReport();
            obj.ttle = "Item Wise Profit & Loss report from " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " to " + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            obj.option = 0;
            obj.ShowDialog();

        con.Close();
    }
```

one 'i' loop is taking around 4 secs to execute, I have around 8000 records and 
(items)1000+(dealers)400 conditions.

This part is taking long time to execute:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(Qty),sum(rate) from SalesDetails where ItemCode='" + items[i] + "' and dealer='" + dealers[j] + "' and date between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' group by ItemCode,Dealer", con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Its too long time how to solve the problem. Indexing is not allowed in my table structure.
Any other solution will be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You should also identify the exact part which is slow. You have multiple `'i'` loops, which one do you mean (although it is probably fair to assume the DB access one, you need to be clear)

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(Qty),sum(rate) from SalesDetails where ItemCode='" + items[i] + "' and dealer='" + dealers[j] + "' and date between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' group by ItemCode,Dealer", con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: 4 seconds isn't that bad, especially if you are not allowed to improve the SQL indexing in anyway. Put the effort in to do what NoIdeaForName suggested and you will get a noticeable improvement. It's a pain, but will be worth it!

Comment: its not 4 secs , its (4*1000) i.e. 4000 secs. If you read the whole code you will get it.

Answer (score 2):

first of all i didn't understand if the query to the DB is taking too long or the rest of the function or both.

if you don't know, you should start by testing it. you can use a simple `DateTime.Now` and see how many ticks did each part took.

if you want to test it with an even better way, you can use StopWatch as as V4Vendetta said. you can find an example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) and basically the syntext will be like:

```
// Create new stopwatch
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing
stopwatch.Start();

// YOUR CODE HERE

// Stop timing
stopwatch.Stop();

// Write result
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
    stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

for the DB access is the one that take too long i can advise you not to call too many sql queries. i see that in a `for` loop you are calling:

"select slno from SalesDetails where..."

might be better to get all the table and use linq instead. that way you save a lot of DB calls. same goes to the rest of your DB queries, i think we can use up to 3-5 DB calls.

Comment: Would avoid `DateTime` for such measurements .. use a [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: @V4Vendetta stopwatch is an excellent tool but i see the code and thinking this is someone that just started programming not long ago. i wanted to give him the minimal understanding needed tool

Comment: But `StopWatch` is the right tool for such things, its better for a starter to know the right tools for the job

Comment: @V4Vendetta i've added a part on stopwatch.